# Using xcode 6 and Swift, how can I grab all objectIds from a class on parse and put them into an array?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am making a tiny quiz app to help my students study for tests.  I have the questions on parse.com and successfully can query objects by their ID one at a time, but I end up having to hard code all the objectIds, and what I would like to do is grab the objectIds, put them into an array, and then pull a random question/objectID from that array as the students click through the questions.

I'm a novice, so ... while I may be able to understand the logic, I'm not sure how to write the code.
Here is the code I'm currently using ... but it doesn't include my failed attempts to put the object IDs in an array.  I've been trying to add a function CallIDs() with a parse query to get them all, but so far ... no luck.  Any ideas?

import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var ObjectIDs : [String]!
var Question  : String!
var Answers   : [String]!
var Answer    : String!



@IBOutlet var QuestionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var AnswerResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Next: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var QuizInstructions: UILabel!


var RandomID = 0





override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   Hide()

   CallData()

}



func GetRandomObjectID() {

    ObjectIDs = ["jr92lfjbQc","r0C8oC4aJ6","XbTTX8xBRf","cjV2z4PSvV","wATbbu0JoX","9Y6HzfeeoD","mNHCMaao41","5qRcqyyXOL","JaLCoeyA1T","nrnifGOP1T","aDAQ6t3saJ","jKF0ZhmPxh"]

    RandomID = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ObjectIDs.count)))


}







func CallData() {

    GetRandomObjectID()

    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(ObjectIDs[RandomID]) {
        (ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in


        if (error == nil) {
            self.Question = ObjectHolder ["Question"] as String!
            self.Answers = ObjectHolder ["Answers"] as Array!
            self.Answer = ObjectHolder ["Answer"] as String!

            if (self.Answers.count > 0) {
                self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question

                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[0], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button2.setTitle(self.Answers[1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button3.setTitle(self.Answers[2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button4.setTitle(self.Answers[3], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            }


        } else {

            NSLog("Something is wrong, dude.  Sorry.")
        }


    }

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func Hide() {
    AnswerResult.hidden = true
    Next.hidden = true
}


func UnHide() {
    AnswerResult.hidden = false
    Next.hidden = false
}


@IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    UnHide()
    if (Answer == "0") {
        AnswerResult.text = "Woot! That's correct!"
    } else {
        AnswerResult.text = "Nope. Try Again."
    }
}

@IBAction func Button2Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    UnHide()
    if (Answer == "1") {
        AnswerResult.text = "Woot! That's correct!"
    } else {
        AnswerResult.text = "Nope. Try Again."
    }
}

@IBAction func Button3Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    UnHide()
    if (Answer == "2") {
        AnswerResult.text = "Woot! That's correct!"
    } else {
        AnswerResult.text = "Nope. Try Again."
    }

}

@IBAction func Button4Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    UnHide()
    if (Answer == "3") {
        AnswerResult.text = "Woot! That's correct!"
    } else {
        AnswerResult.text = "Nope. Try Again."
    }
}


@IBAction func Next(sender: AnyObject) {
    CallData()
    Hide()
}
```

}

/////  well ... here is the function I attempted to code, but it isn't working:

```
  func CallIDs() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: “QuestionsandAnswers”) 
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in 
    for object in objects {
    self.objectIdsArray.append(object.objectId)
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get a compile error?

Comment: Hmmm, good question ... thank you ... the func CallIDs( ) I'm trying to incorporate to replace the hard coded objectIds is what isn't working.  No compile errors b/c I never made it that far ... tons of in line errors -- those little red dots that say there is a problem with the code -- (lots of different errors as I've tried different things) Hope it's just semantics.

Comment: Bueller?  Bueller?   My bad ... I should have just posted the erroneous function and not all that other code ... mea culpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the underlying misunderstanding in this question is that objects are to be retrieved using their ids.  The requirement is for a random object, and that can be achieved better by knowing only the *count* of the objects stored on the server.

Getting the count we can select a random object by setting a random skip for a query.  So, in the completion block of `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, get a random number up to that count like this:

```
let randomSkip = arc4random_uniform(count)
```

Now we're ready to do a query with no object id, setting `query.skip = randomSkip`, and `query.limit = 1`.

**EDIT** - If I were to build this in Objective-C, I would do it as follows:

```
- (void)randomQuestion:(void (^)(NSString *question, NSArray *answers))completion {
    PFQuery *countQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"QuestionsandAnswers"];
    [countQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
        NSInteger randomSkip = arc4random_uniform(count);
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"QuestionsandAnswers"];
        query.skip = randomSkip;
        query.limit = 1;
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                if (objects.count) {
                    PFObject *questionAndAnswerObject = objects[0];
                    NSString *question = questionAndAnswerObject[@"Question"];
                    NSArray *answers = questionAndAnswerObject[@"Answers"];
                    completion(question, answers);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"no error, but no Q&A objects found");
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"there was an error %@", error);
                completion(nil, nil);
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yes!  Not so much a misunderstanding as it is a limitation of ability.  Following tutorials etc., the only way I've been able to successfully retrieve data is with the objectId.  I'm not astute enough in xcode to write a for each loop like I would in php.  I like this answer, if only I could fully comprehend it.  :-)   So, you think I could rewrite/restructure the CallData function to work this way???  Thank you, btw.  Researching randomSkip now ...

Comment: Hi danh, I've been trying to work this solution, but have found no joy.  Could you maybe show me a generic example of what you're saying in code?  I by no means want to ask anyone to code for me, because then, what would I learn?  But if you could show a generic example in a function or something, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: I did my best in the answer to dance around the fact that I don't speak Swift very fluently, but I guess the jig is up.  I'll edit now and provide my best idea in Objective-C.

Comment: Wow, thank you!!!  No worries ... even an example in objective C would be a huge huge help.  :-)

Comment: Thank you, danh!!!  I'm about to put another question asking how to incorporate this into swift ... in generic terms, of course.  :-)  Except I'm adding a third generic variable to represent the answer for the question.  Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you declare the array `objectIdsArray`. I was unable to find it. However the reason you may be having trouble replacing an existing array is because the function you are calling, `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` does not run on the main thread. The code will continue to execute rather then waiting for the objectIds to download.

In order to make sure that you have downloaded the objectIds first before you try to use them, you may want to use the following code:

```
func CallIDs() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: “QuestionsandAnswers”) 
    query.selectKeys(["objectId"])
    self.objectIdsArray = query.findObjects()
    }
```

Note: When run, you should see the following message:

> Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.

However I have not yet found this to be a problem. If the download is quick, it should not be noticeable. If it is taking a considerable amount of time, you can add in a UIActivityIndicatorView.

Comment: It is inadvisable in iOS to use the synchronous find on the main thread.  Parse provides withBlock versions of everything, including find.  A UIActivityIndicatorView is no solution.  It won't be made visible until the app returns to the run loop, and it can't be properly removed unless you know when the find finishes.

Comment: You are right, I didn't declare the objectIdsArray ... bit of a typo there ... should just be ObjectIDs ... that's the trouble with being a novice ... you read and watch tutorials, grasp some of it and end up making Frankenstein code that invaribly has some extra bits here and there.

Comment: Thank you Danh!  I am looking into your random skip idea.  See, I would like to structure the app/code so that if needed, I could add more questions to the parse class without having to update the app, hence the need to avoid hard coding object ids.  It seems like your count/random skip idea would certainly work.  Now I just gotta figure how to code that.  Thank you for the input.